# After powering off ubuntu it loads bios startup screen

Tags: shutdown

So normally shutting down ubuntu it doesn't turn off the computer but instead loads the bios boot menu where you can press F11 or del. Nothing has changed on the computer in any way, software or hardware. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that this used to work fine and now it's rebooting into BIOS instead of powering off (or it powers off, then immediately powers on again).

There could be a number of reasons, WARNING: Some of these tips may stop your computer from booting if something goes wrong. Be careful.

1. Kernel bug. Try an older kernel. In GRUB, go to `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and select older kernels. See if that fixes it. You could also try the newer HWE kernels via `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`.
2. Corrupted CMOS settings. Unplug your computer. Clear the CMOS via jumper.
3. Firmware bug. Update your BIOS to latest version (careful....)
4. Electrical wiring issue: There may be a short somewhere between the pins and the power button, causing the motherboard to receive a "power on" signal right after shutdown
5. Mechanical/electrical problem. The power button may be broken and sending sporadic false presses (doubtful because this would also mean your computer would randomly turn off unless you've configured it to ignore the power button)

Trying to power off from a LiveUSB Ubuntu (try various versions, i.e. 18.04, 20.04, 22.04) is a quick way to rule out various of these causes (i.e. if it powers off fine, it's likely a kernel problem).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. It is not my computer so I don't have access to it now. But my impression is that it doesn't turn off and then turn back on but instead goes pretty much straight to that bios screen when shutting down computer in ubuntu. I'll ask more questions.